# Text Input Placeholder Changes With Menu Item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Have a quick question regarding dynamic placeholder text. I have a material ui select menu with 3 menu items: name, email, and phone. I want the input box next to it to change placeholder text depending on which menu item is currently selected, i.e. Search by name, search by email, search by phone. How would I go about doing this? Very new to React so I'm still learning.

Comment: Hello, first take a look at this doc and come back to us with some details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store select's value in a react state and change the input's placeholder according to that state's value:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("name");

return (
  <>
    <Select
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem value="name">name</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="email">email</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="phone">phone</MenuItem>
    </Select>

    <input placeholder={`search by ${value}`} />
  </>
);
```